# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Sanclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SANIKA K\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/"); 

}

}
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

Comment: Did you create a class called `WebDriver` or `ChromeDriver`?

Comment: Something in your project setup or imports is incorrect. There are many guides on the web, I would find some and follow them to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you cant convert a WebDriver to a ChromeDriver like that. Try to start your driver like this instead:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
         .usingDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/chromedriver.exe"))
         .usingAnyFreePort()
         .build();
     service.start();
   }
```

Reference: 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html